# How to stack multiple plots as one plot in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Using a Python lib like Matplotlib or Seaborn, I want to create a single figure which looks like this:[image]

At the intervals on the x-axis (5,10, etc.) I want the curves not to be connected, and I also need the grey vertical line at each interval value .

Comment: please show your code. particularly how you generate the plots.

Comment: There are examples in the Matplotlib documentation that show pretty much all the features on your picture. It's a bit unclear which part you're particularly interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some data for the plot

```
X1=np.linspace(0,5,6)
X2=np.linspace(5,10,6)
Y1=np.random.normal(0.8,1,(6,))
Y2=np.random.normal(0.85,0.9,(6,))
```

Let's put them together and reproduce your style

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X1,Y1)
ax.plot(X2,Y2)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,10,3))
ax.xaxis.grid(True,linestyle='--')
```

[image: output]

Answer (score -2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

x =  np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,1000)
fig , ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,np.cos(x))
ax.plot(x,np.sin(x))
```

This is a way to superpose different plot on same x-axis and y-axis.